# Sass - how to make the sass-box responsive on all screen sizes

Tags: css, sass

I am using sass on my web project. At the moment,  my sass-box has a height of 100 percent. The problem is that if the height,  is 100 percent, it only covers up to where the content of the page ends. It does not cover the rest of the page and this is then left blank with no colour on it.

I have tried using 1000px; etc but then the problem is that on some pages of the site the sass-box becomes too big in height, and you are able to scroll down the page even when a lot of its blank.

The question is, can you make it so that the sass-box adjusts to screen sizes and covers all the visible page even if there is not a full page of content? and if there is a full page of content, it covers everything?

Comment: This isn't a Sass issue, it's a CSS issue.  Use [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh) instead of a percent.

Comment: I've tried using vh but it covers the full size of the screen and if you scroll down on pages that have more content, the sass box doesn't cover that space